# Cowboy handler and custom gen_server link

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I'm trying to implement REST handler which communicates to custom
gen_servers.

Get gen_server from supervisor and link to current handler process:

```
rest_init(Req, _Opts) ->
...
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  {ok, Pid} = pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration(),
  link(Pid),
...

make_get(Req, State) ->
....
make error here !!!
....
```

And gen_server code:
    start_link() ->
      gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

```
init(Args) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  {ok, []}.

handle_info({'EXIT', FromPid, Reason}, State) ->
  lager:info("Exit Logic from ~p  Reason: ~p~n", [FromPid, Reason]),
  {noreply, State};
```

So I expect to receive EXIT signal from REST handler to my gen_server when
error occurs in cowboy.
But I don't receive it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your processes must be linked to receive EXIT signal. It's not clear to me where the processes links to each other in your code sample.

Comment: Handler calls supervisor method {ok, Pid} = pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration(), and supervisor is simple_one_for_one which just starts a child: supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).

Comment: It's strange. Could you show a source code of pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration()? And one more question. Did you try to call link from init() of gen_server process?

Comment: Sup: 
start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

%% ===================================================================
%% Supervisor callbacks
%% ===================================================================

init([]) ->
  {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 0, 1}, [{pbshare_logic_registration,
    {pbshare_logic_registration, start_link, []}, temporary, 1000, worker, [pbshare_logic_registration]}]}}.

start_registration() ->
  supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []).

Comment: I make link in cowboy handler because gen_server doesn't know about cowboy anything. rest_init(Req, _Opts) ->
...
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  {ok, Pid} = pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration(),
  link(Pid),

Comment: You can link in gen_server's init() callback if you pass the pid of your cowboy process to starting fuction of process. It's something like that: {ok, Pid} = pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration(self())

Comment: It will be the same when I make link in cowboy handler:  {ok, Pid} = pbshare_logic_sup:start_registration(), link(Pid), Link is bidirectional and I think it doesn't matter where to make linking.

Comment: I know that link is bidirectional. But it may help to find out where mistake is.

Comment: I tried to make linking in gen_server instead of cowboy handler: init(Args) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  link(Args),
But without success. When handler crashes my gen_server receives terminate normal action without any argument and it doesn't receive EXIT message. So as I said it doesn't matter from what side to make link. handler hasn't still receive EXIT action :(